# Python logger confusion

Tags: python-3.x, logging, filehandler

I am trying to understand the python logging, and I have this:

> **Main.py**:

```
import logging
from Foo import Foo

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

fh_formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(name)s] : %(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('logger.log', mode='w')
file_handler.setFormatter(fh_formatter)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

sh_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setFormatter(sh_formatter)
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

logger.info('Running main')
Foo().print_foo()
```

> **Foo.py**

```
import logging
from Bar import Bar

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Foo():

    def print_foo(self):
        Bar().print_bar()
        logger.info('Inside Foo.foo')
```

> **Bar.py:**

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Bar():

    def print_bar(self):
        logger.info('Inside Bar.bar')
```

When I run the code, on the console I see this **output**:

```
Running main
INFO:__main__:Running main
INFO:Bar:Inside Bar.bar
INFO:Foo:Inside Foo.foo
```

But when I check the `logger.log`, I see only one line

```
[2019-03-23 18:46:01,276 : INFO : __main__] : Running main
```

How can I make it so that I see all the lines in both the places? Do I need to set a file handler and stream handler for each logger in each file? If I have a python project, and I want to have a single log file along with console output, what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on this line in Foo and Bar:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Note that you only reset the logging handler in `Main.py`, with the logger name of `__name__`, which resolved to `"__main__"` as you can see in the output. When you get the logger from `Foo.py`, your logger name is `"Foo"` and hence everything you set to `"__main__"` is not applied.

What you want to do: Change the `__name__` part. For example, your app is called `fubar` then you do this in `Main.py`:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("fubar")
```

and in `Foo.py`, as a submodule in the app, do this:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("fubar.Foo")
```

Or you can even use the same name if you wish. This way, the handler assigned at higher level will pass on to sub-levels.